# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: apex, rest-api, ssl

I am trying to call one URL through apex callouts but it is throwing this exception : "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
The same call is working with Postman/RESTlet Client.
Can anyone tell me the exact issue. I am not getting it.